# C#: FastColoredTextBox not updating syntax highlighting after modifying editor.Text property

Tags: c#

I am using FastColoredTextBox to introduce syntax highlighting in my top secret C# project. In the OpenFile() method I have the following code:

```
try
{
    editor.Clear();
    editor.InsertText(File.ReadAllText(filename));
    editor.OnTextChanged(0, editor.LinesCount - 1);
    currFilename = filename;
    ChangeWindowLabel();
    return true;
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to open file:\n\n" + ex.Message, Core.Product, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return false;
}
```

However, I have the following problem: After opening the file in the editor, the syntax highlighting does not seem to be applied. I set up my styling rules in editor's TextChanged event I manually fire in code above:

```
private void editor_TextChanged(object sender, FastColoredTextBoxNS.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.ChangedRange.ClearStyle(CommentStyle);
    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(CommentStyle, @"!.*(\r\n)?$");

    e.ChangedRange.ClearStyle(StartEndStyle);
    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(StartEndStyle, @"^DL (Start|End)(\r\n)?$");

    // and so on...

    e.ChangedRange.SetFoldingMarkers(@"^\t*For\(.*\)", @"\$\$\$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

How to enforce recoloring in entire document? Is this a FCTB bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your regular expression, that's not a FCTB bug.

Replace this line:

```
  e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(StartEndStyle, @"^DL (Start|End)(\r\n)?$");
```

with this one:

```
  e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(StartEndStyle, @"DL (Start|End)");
```